# SwiftUI Preview Canvas Not Shown

Tags: swift, swiftui, preview

I have a project running with iOS 13.0 which consists of a framework (Common) which contains all views and an app target which uses the framework to display the UI. The project itself builds fine.

When I want to implement a preview in RatingView.swift the canvas view says `Failed to build RatingView.swift` and `'RatingView' is not a member type of 'Common'`. I do the preview like this:

```swift
#if DEBUG
import SwiftUI
struct RatingViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return RatingView()
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: UIView, context: Context) {}
}

struct RatingView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RatingViewRepresentable()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Well my project builds fine but the  (extra) build started by the preview canvas actually fails with this error message. So this is actually relevant. Fixed a typo though `RatingCellPreview  > RatingView_Preview `